CounterExamples on Geometry form of Hahn-Banach theorem
I'm trying to solve some exercise about counter examples of HB thm of separations.
Example:
Let $X=(L^2([0, 1];\mathbb{R}), \lVert \rVert_2)$ with Lebesgue measure,
Let $A= ${$ f\in X|f \in C([0, 1];\mathbb{R}), f(0)>0$},
Let $B=${$f\in X|f \in C([0, 1];\mathbb{R}), f(0)<0$},
Then A and B are two disjoint convex set of X such that they don't separate on X, in the sense of HB thm obviously.


A and B are trivially convex and disjoint.
In order to prove the non-separability i try to assume by absurd that $\exists F\in X^*-${$0$} such that $F(a)\leq F(b) \, \forall a \in A, b \in B$,
Then $F(a)-F(b)=F(a-b)=F(h) \leq 0 \, \forall h \in A-B$, but by definition $A-B=A$ then we can say that $F(a) \leq 0 \leq F(b) \forall a \in A, b \in B$.
I'm trying to find some reason for which F must be the null fuctional and coclude by absurd, but i'm block at this point.

Note that there is a very explicit way to describe the bounded linear functionals on $L^2$ using Riesz theorem. Perhaps you should try to use that.

$A$ and $B$ are both dense in $L^2([0,1])$.

We can easily see that both $A$ and $B$ are dense in $L^2$. A continuous linear functional $F: L^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ with $F(a) \leq F(b)$ for all $a \in A$ and $b \in B$ must thus have $0 \leq F(b - a)$. Hence $F(b - a) = 0$, but the set $B - A$ is still dense in $X$, so we must have $F = 0$.
